# Disabling buttons in jQueryMobile - SimpleDialog2 dialog

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jQueryMobile - SimpleDialog2
as described in http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/button.html

However, I want to disable buttons according to some condition.

Is there any way to do this without hacking the SimpleDialog2 code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but I managed to get a 'disabled' effect by doing this

```
close: (disabled)? false: true,
theme: (disabled)? "c": "b"
```

where 'disabled' my condition.

Hope this helps someone